# How can I get the longtitute/lattitude for a given city/country?

Tags: php, javascript, html

For example when I enter an address on the http://www.infoghidromania.com/harta_romania.html website and then press submit, it should extract the GPS coordinates.

Comment: Right, and what have you done so far?

Comment: JavaScript running on the infoghidromania.com website, or PHP running elsewhere?

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to post a request to that site to calculate a GPS coordinate, wright? You don't control the page itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That site uses the google maps api. You can use the same API to get the longtitude/lattitude for any location you can find on google maps itself.

Javascript code example:

```
var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': '<YOUR_SEARCH_STRING_HERE>' }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        alert("Lang/Lat : " + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + " " +results[0].geometry.location.lng()); 
    } else {
        alert('Error: ' + status);
    }
});
```

Working examples:

- **Example 1**: http://jsfiddle.net/dovereem/kChXa/
- **Example with search box**: http://jsfiddle.net/dovereem/kChXa/1/

Comment: and then ...how can i extract with php regex GPS coordinates?

Comment: Updated. Attached links to examples that probably do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called "geocoding". Google Maps has an API you can use - you can see the details [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

A quick example of how to use it (assuming this is in a file called `latLong.php`):

```
<html encoding="utf-8">

<body>
    Please enter address to look up:
    <form method="get" action="latLong.php">
        <input name="address" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
<?php
    $crlf = "<br>";

    if (isset($_GET["address"])) {
        $addressString = $_GET["address"];
        $address = urlencode($addressString);
        $googleApi = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s&sensor=false';     

        $json = file_get_contents(sprintf($googleApi, $address));   
        $resultObject = json_decode($json);

        $location = $resultObject->results[0]->geometry->location;

        $lat = $location->lat;
        $lng = $location->lng;

        echo "Requested address: ".$addressString.$crlf; 
        echo "Latitude: ".$lat.$crlf;
        echo "Longitude: ".$lng.$crlf;
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $('idOfInputField').val("content");
    $('the id of the form').submit();
});
```